# Electron Error Launching app Unable to find electron app

Tags: reactjs, npm, electron, yarnpkg

I have read through so many post about this problem but for me it's still remain.

I'm building react web application and want to show that in desktop app.

Here are my enviroment version :

```
Node : v10.13.0
Npm : 6.4.1
yarn : 1.12.3
```

At first i try to install electron with my npm in main project but got errors. Therefore i created a new react project using create-react-app via the powershell:

```
npm install -g create-react-app
```

Then i install electron via yarn. I have add all the requirement to package.json and main.js. Below is package.json and main.js

Package.Json:

```
{
  "name": "chat",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "main": "public/main.js",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^16.6.3",
    "react-dom": "^16.6.3",
    "react-scripts": "2.1.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "electron-start": "electron ."

  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": [
    ">0.2%",
    "not dead",
    "not ie <= 11",
    "not op_mini all"
  ],
  "devDependencies": {
    "electron": "^3.0.10"
  }
}
```

main.js

```
const electron = require('electron');
const app = electron.app;
const BrowserWindow = electron.BrowserWindow;
const Menu = electron.Menu;

let mainWindow;

function createWindow() {
  mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({width: 900, height: 680});
  mainWindow.loadURL('http://localhost:3000');

  app.setAboutPanelOptions({
    applicationName: "chat",
    applicationVersion: "0.0.1",
  })

  mainWindow.on('closed', () => mainWindow = null);
}

app.on('ready', createWindow);

app.on('window-all-closed', () => {
  if (process.platform !== 'darwin') {
    app.quit();
  }
});

app.on('activate', () => {
  if (mainWindow === null) {
    createWindow();
  }
});
```

After this i run my local host via script start to access localhost. Then run `yarn run electron-start` to open electron app but got the error : Unable to find electron app.

Comment: This is usually because your running `electron .` in the wrong folder. Can you check that your running it in the same folder as your `package.json` file?

Comment: @Mike yes. I have run electron . in the same folder. Actually i executed the script electron-start in the package.json file.

Comment: Ah ok, I think it might be that it can't find your `main.js` file inside of the `public` folder. Try changing the `electron-start` npm script to: `electron public/main.js`

Comment: @Mike Thanks. I have changed the script to the way you said from electron . to public/main.js but the error still remaining.

Comment: Hmm... ok, can you try running `electron public/main.js` on its own instead of running it inside a script?

Comment: Sorry for bothering you but this error still happen. run the electron command directly not fix this.

Comment: Don't worry about it :) that's what I'm here for. I'm not sure what might be the problem anymore, you would probably have more luck opening a issue on electron's github repo https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/new?template=Bug_report.md

Comment: @Mike Ok Thank for helping me.

Comment: @Mike Sorry but i have found my problem. I accidently create 2 public folder. I link wrong in the package.json therefore i can't open the file

Comment: Ah, that's good to hear, well done on finding the problem +1